# share a message in Linkedin via windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

want to share a link from my application in windows phone 7. Any one know a good API library for this.....I have downloaded a API from a site which shows null information like this

Usage
1. Create a button that sends the user to a page where the login process will start like LinkedInBeginAuth.aspx or Account/LinkedInBeginAuth in MVC

2.Inside LinkedInBeginAuth Page add the following code

1. Create the page that the user will be redirected after login
2. Inside that page add

5.That's it!

Library is in EARLY development so expect major changes. Use it wisely.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what is being asked for here. Could you please try to clarify your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the LinkedIn API you'll need to connect via OAuth. (You can do this with Hammock & a WebBrowser control.)

Once connected you can call their [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest).

Alternatively, or possibly as a starting point, you could look at http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/ but it doesn't look complete.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the ShareStatusTask :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: I want to share a message to linkedin from my windows mobile application i need an API for that

Comment: I want to share a message to linkedin from my windows mobile application i need an API for that – using hammock

Comment: @Senthilkumar.SM If the user has linked their LinkedIn account to their phone then the ShareStatusTask will let you post to LinkedIn.