# Linkedin login api windows phone 7 and search people

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-7, linkedin-api

Ho i'm trying to do an application that search people information on linkedin but i have some problem with the login step,anyone can help me ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you not mentioned what you have done and not share your code so i can help you with some good tutorials for it.

- [linkedin-from-a-windows-phone-app](http://buildmobile.com/linkedin-from-a-windows-phone-app/)
- http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1230(download **LinkedInAuth.rar.zip**)

Also can see..

- [share a message in Linkedin via windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128466/share-a-message-in-linkedin-via-windows-phone)